# How to override jquery _blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm including a widget in a page using PHP. The widget includes the following jQuery code, which is making all links open in an external page. Is there any way to override or neutralize this code so it no longer affects all links on the page?

Ideally, I'd like to wrap the widget in a div and specify those links to open in a `_blank`.

I am new to jQuery, so I appreciate any help offered.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // change all links to open outside iframe
  $("a").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("rel", "external").attr("target","_blank");
  });
});
```

Comment: What have  you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you do as you say and wrap your widget in a div like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Your widget -->
</div>
```

You can select only the links inside that container like this:

```
$(".container a").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("rel", "external").attr("target","_blank");
});
```

`.container a` selects anchor elements (links) that are children to that containing div, and will run your function on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try it code

```js
$(window).ready(function() {
  $("a").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("rel", "external").attr("target","_blank");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.france24.com/en/tag/peace/">Peace of Paris</a>
```